# How can I use google cloud functions to schedule a python script that works with python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

One of the dependencies in my python script works with python 3.6 - it doesn't work with python 3.7.

I'm trying to deploy it as an app in google app engine with a flexible environment *(i'm struggling with it)* BUT it would be so much easier if I could set it up as a cloud function and schedule it with cloud pub/sub & cloud scheduler.

So, is there a way for me to make my python 3.6 script work with cloud functions which has a python 3.7 runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Python 3.6 with Cloud Functions as there is no Python 3.6 runtime (and there won't be).

Instead, you could use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run), as it will allow you to use *any* Python version for your runtime. For example, the following `Dockerfile` would run your app with Python 3.6:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install Flask gunicorn

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

You'd need to convert your script to an endpoint in a Flask app, but that's basically equivalent to converting it to a Cloud Function.

Comment: When you deploy your Cloud Run you can set your concurrency param to 1 for having exactly the same behavior that you have with Cloud Functions (only 1 request is processed in the same time on an instance)

Comment: Thank you, I managed to deploy on cloud run - at first look, it seems to be way easier to use than app engine! I still got to figure out how to create a pub/sub topic from it but that a whole different thing :D